# how can i put one DIV behind another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

i'm doing my first project but i had some problems with divs: i want to put the firework behind the central text but i don't understand how to do it. Can you please help me?

i have to write more details otherwise i can't upload the question. If you want to know what is my project about, it's like a birhday invite for my 18° bithday, i'm trying to do something different .

here is the code, thanks.

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

.centro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.center-text {
  color: #E7ECEF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  width: 30%;
}

.firework {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.explosion {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.explosion:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(30deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(150deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(210deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotate(330deg) translateY(-15px);
}

.explosion:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: explosion 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes explosion {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
  }
  33%,
  100% {
    top: -50%;
  }
}

#firework1 {
  transform: scale(1);
  transform: translateX(-60px) translateY(-150px);
}

#firework1 .explosion::before {
  background-color: #ffde71;
  animation: explosion 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="centro">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="center-text">
        compleanno di <span class="typing center-text"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="firework" id="firework1">
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
      <div class="explosion"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Apply z-index: 2; to your text. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Not sure I understand which sense of 'behind' you mean. Is it in the z-direction (in which case watch out for stacking context which may mean z-index doesn't work) or is it that you'd like the firework to be more 'in amongst' the text (at the moment on a large screen it appears above the text, on a smaller one it only slightly overlaps).

Answer (score 0):

you can move it to the front with the `z-index` element.

```
.text {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
z-index : 5;
```

}